# Android Studio is extremely slow and become faster after few hours

Tags: performance, android-studio, ide

i'm driving crazy about this, i don't know how to solve.

My Android Studio (Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2) is extremely slow, it has a delay of 1-2s when i type something, but, weirdly, after some hours of use it become fast as it should be.

This problem starts 2 weeks ago, i don't know what changed but i assure that before that "point", Android studio was perfect, without problem.

How can i solve? I tried all tutorial / tips to make it faster but nothing works.

I have a Macbook pro M1 with 16gb RAM, i think that's not the problem.

Any solution?

Thank you!

I tried all of this:

- Repair IDE (executing all suggestions)
- Invalidate Cache (marking all checkboxes)
- Increase ReservedCodeCacheSize

  ```
  -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1024m
  ```
- Increase memory allocation pool

  ```
  -Xmx3096m
  ```
- Avoid using android emulator